# Configuring a static site within Django Framework

Tags: python, django

I have designed a static website. But I need to incorporate dynamic features in it after 3 months. So, I decided to configure it with django framework before uploading. But I see, I need to configure all the URL in `urls.py`. Is there any other way of configuring a static site?

This may sound silly but thought of hearing from SO as I need to configure a lot of URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`flatpages` application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/flatpages/). It allows you to generate flat (or *static* as you want, but the term static is generally reserved to refer to CSS, JS and images files in the Django world.) pages through the administration.

You just have to set a URL prefix (not mandatory, you can go for the *catchall* method) and create each page in the administration (which allows HTML). When you will have your dynamic pages, the `urls.py` should be like:

```
urlpatterns = ('',
    (r'^page1$', 'view1'),
    (r'^page2$', 'view2'),
)
# Other URL are redirect to flatpage app
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.flatpages.views',
    (r'^(?P<url>.*/)$', 'flatpage'),
)
```

If the flatpage doesn't exist, the application will return a 404 HTTP error. You can also customize the base template, as explained in the doc, by creating a file `flatpages/default.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ flatpage.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
   <nav>My super menu</nav>
   <section>
       {{ flatpage.content }}
   </section>
   <footer>
       &copy; My name - 2014
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

It forces you to have all your flat pages into the database but it is kind of easier to change URL and content after all.